# Reflectively get all fields in a Java Interface?

Tags: java

Is it possible to reflectively get all fields in a java interface?  for example :

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class field1 {

    private double d;  
    public static final int i = 37;  
    String s = "testing";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("field1");

            Field fieldlist[] = cls.getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldlist.length; i++) {
                Field fld = fieldlist[i];
                System.out.println("name= " + fld.getName());
                System.out.println("-----");
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
   }
}
```

FIXED!!

I forgot to add full classpath in Class.forName("field1"); should be **Class.forName("com.x.y.z.field1");**

Comment: my bad, was not giving full path name, thanks for quick reply though

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the previous comment because I saw your update. :)

Comment: There is no field in the interface.

Comment: @gigadot There is no *interface* here for there to be fields in, but interfaces can certainly contain fields.

Comment: @EJP, Thanks. I didn't think about the constant fields in the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to reflectively get all fields in a java interface?

Certainly. The same code you have here should work on an interface. Bear in mind that any fields you get from an interface will be both `static` and `final`.